# How to copy a directory in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

Is there a library which allows me to copy a directory and all subdirectories in Clojure? Something like:

> `(copy "source-dir" "destination-dir")`

Comment: Use recursion, Luke. Downvote is mine since the question does not show any effort put in solving the problem. To copy a directory you recursively copy it file by file.

Comment: Yes I know that, but I like to reuse code first before I reinvent the wheel, called DRY

Comment: here is the library https://github.com/Raynes/fs . My answer does not satisfy stackoverflow quality standard so I put it in comment.

Comment: DRY is not about using libraries or reinventing wheels, not even close.

Comment: @zerkms Yes you right about DRY, my mistake. But we have libraries in Clojure. It is always better to use libraries for things that have already been written

Comment: @mavbozo Thanks, that is exactly what I needed. If you can get it as the answer then I will choose it as the accepted answer

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @developerbmw Which Stack Exchange is the correct site for finding libraries then? I will move the question there

Comment: @Zubair google is for searching. If you put your exact question title to https://google.com you would find that library as the very first item. That's why you need to put some effort **BEFORE** you ask a question.

Comment: @Zubair it's not a stack exchange site, but it's called Google. I googled "clojure copy directory" and the first result was the one linked to in the accepted answer.

Comment: "Google", I have never heard of that, but I'll check it out. Thanks for the hint

Comment: Also: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html

Comment: developerbmw, you're right, some of the these answers *are* very opinionated.  (There's some spam about some product called "Google", too.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the following code for `copy-dir`:

> copy-dir (copy-dir from to)
>
> Copy a directory from `from` to `to`. If
>   `to` already exists, copy the directory to a directory with the same
>   name as `from` within the `to` directory.

```
(defn copy-dir
  "Copy a directory from `from` to `to`. If `to` already exists, copy the directory
   to a directory with the same name as `from` within the `to` directory."
  [from to]
  (when (exists? from)
    (if (file? to)
      (throw (IllegalArgumentException. (str to " is a file")))
      (let [from (file from)
            to (if (exists? to)
                 (file to (base-name from))
                 (file to))
            trim-size (-> from str count inc)
            dest #(file to (subs (str %) trim-size))]
        (mkdirs to)
        (dorun
         (walk (fn [root dirs files]
                 (doseq [dir dirs]
                   (when-not (directory? dir)
                     (-> root (file dir) dest mkdirs)))
                 (doseq [f files]
                   (copy+ (file root f) (dest (file root f)))))
               from))
        to))))
```

Or directly use the [fs library](http://raynes.github.io/fs/) available on [Github](https://github.com/Raynes/fs).

Comment: @Zubair asking for libraries is explicitly off-topic as per http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @developerbmw Then please vote to close this question, that is your right

Comment: @developerbmw I upvoted your comment showing the stack overflow link. If you had stated that in the first place I would have understood, so thanks for that

Comment: @Zubair glad I helped :) Sorry I should have linked to that in the first comment.

Comment: @developerbmw No problem. Anyway, the problem is solved now. I would have deleted the question, but since Stephane took the time to answer it I will leave it up there for now

Comment: @Stéphane Bruckert Sorry you got downvoted by others. Apparently they are punishing you for answering a question in good faith. The mistake was mine, not yours. Just say if you want me to delete the question

Comment: @DavidShaked you will find other defs here https://github.com/Raynes/fs/blob/master/src/me/raynes/fs.clj#L101

Answer (score 1):

You can use `copy-dir` of the [`fs library`](https://github.com/Raynes/fs) as already answered.

One issue with `copy-dir` is that it'll put the source directory under the target directory if the target directory already exists behaving like:

```
# if target already exists
cp -r source/ target/ 
# target/source/...
```

To avoid this, you can use the [`copy-dir-into`](https://github.com/Raynes/fs/blob/147f7b30d2c3c7e773a3650bf16a7b5720acfde8/src/me/raynes/fs.clj#L534) function. It will behave something like this:

```
cp -r source/* target/
```

It's not in [the document](http://raynes.github.io/fs/me.raynes.fs.html) but it's a public function so it should be safe to use.